# How can I do a python API request with the body?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, postman

if I do a POST request on Postman with my local API server it works:

[image]

But if I try in python with this syntax it doesn't work:
`requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add', data={'path': 'test'}).text`

it returns:
`"file argument 'path' is required\n"`

Can you please explain me why it doesn't work?

Comment: You probably meant `data={'path':'test'}` instead

Comment: Yes, I modified the example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that using `data` on `requests.post` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while your application wants `multipart/form-data`. Try using `files` instead of `data`:

```py
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add', files={'path': 'test'}).text
```

Answer (score 0):

If I pass the files parameter instead of data or json, it works!

```
requests.post(url = api_url, files={'path':'test'}).text
```